# Searching through data inside data with excel formula

Tags: excel, ms-office, formula

this is my first time asking here, I hope I didn't asked in the wrong section.

[image]

I have three other cells that contain for example: "X", "IPS", "2".
The goal is to return the value of the cell under column "Nama" with the same row as the three information given from the three cells.

There will be random people's name under column "Nama". And like what I said, there are three cells that are changeable, these cells will give information about what name should appear on that one output cell.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, if your three cells are A1:C1 (in order) then:

```
="Nama Wali Kelas "&A1&" "&B1&" "&C1
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I gave you wrong explanation.

There will be random people's name under column "Nama". And like what I said, there are three cells that are changeable, these cells will give information about what name to appear on that one output cell.